# AVAudioPlayer can't hear any sound using swift 2.1

Tags: ios, iphone

i try to make iOS app to play some funny sound put when i click play no sound are out from speaker here is the code :

```
@IBAction func slow(sender: UIButton) {
    if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("io", withExtension: "mp3") {

    let _a = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePath)
            // Play

          _a.play()

      }else
    {

        print("error")
    }  
}
```

there is no error but i can't hear any sound at all

Comment: No  have this file "file:///Users/araby/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C901919E-138A-42C5-9903-1D4D7132AC48/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DD852301-19AD-4068-B5FE-E55F1957535C/Sound%20Kick.app/io.mp3
"

Comment: and i resolve it by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for how that face this problem

```
@IBAction func slow(sender: UIButton) {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("io", ofType:"mp3") {

        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()

    }
    else
    {

        print("error")
    }    
}
}
```